# li element backgrounds not obeying the border radius on transformations

Tags: html, css

The code in the `JSFiddle` below creates a menu bar that has a border around it. I thought it might be nice if I added an effect on the `li` element when you click it to help show that the `li` element is `active`. To do this I put the following translation on the `li` element when it is `active`

```
box-shadow: 0 -3px hsl(180, 0%, 22%);
@include transform(translate(0, 2px)); //SCSS Mixin which acts the same as transform: translate(0, 2px);
@include transition(all, 0.25s); //SCSS Mixin which acts the same as transition: all 0.25s;
```

However, when I used this code, I noticed that the background of the `li` element didn't follow the border radius whilst the transition was taking place. So I did some research and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358226/4601149) to a question which found the same problem. However, this did not provide a solution for me. I would appreciate any help in making the background follow the border radius.

*See the image for a visual aid of the problem and the `JSFiddle` for a code example*

[image: Shows border breaking <code>li</code> background]

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/1a81t18y/15/)

Comment: Which browser? For me its working fine...

Comment: @Andreas Latest version of chrome on windows 10

Comment: Ah sorry my fault, now im seeing it ;)

Comment: @Andreas Do you know what is causing it?

Comment: Long story short, during the transition, the a doesn't have any border radius.  You have to add a border radius specifically to the buttons "inside" for it to not show them.  For instance, if you put border-radius: 20px; inside every style, it will make all the buttons round, and you won't have the problem any more (except now your buttons are round).  It's not animating the outer portion with the border-radius; it's animating what's inside with no border-radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this can still be solved by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878279/overflowhidden-ignored-with-border-radius-and-css-transforms-webkit-only/26358226#26358226) but instead of placing `position: relative` and `z-index: 1` in the li elements it should be placed in the `ul` parent.

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  ...
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/1a81t18y/16/) for example of it working like it should.